# how to handle php var_dump after ob_get_clean as an array

Tags: php

The follow is my code

```
<?php
ob_start();
$incoming = var_dump($_REQUEST);
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$incoming = ob_get_content();
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fwrite($fh, $incoming);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

and it generates a file named testFile with the content sent to it..

So, if I navigate to http://example.com/uploads/upload_file.php?key=value

the text file will look like

```
array(1) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(5) "value"
}
```

However, all I want in it, is **just** value

Ive attempted changing the write call to

```
fwrite($fh, $incoming[0]);
```

However, it will just write a to the file as a is from the array(1) portion of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
<?php
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
foreach($_REQUEST as $k => $v)
   fwrite($fh, $v);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: While this works, I dont always know what the item is going to be called. 'Key' will change without my knowledge